Why is "today" separated into "To day
“But exhort one another daily, while it is called To day; lest any of you be hardened through the deceitfulness of sin.”
‭‭Hebrews‬ ‭3‬:‭13‬ ‭KJV‬‬

For the same reason the King James Version (1611) has “To morrow” in Exodus 8:10:

It was considered the proper spelling of both words in 1611 (sometimes hyphenated, i.e., “to-morrow”, “to-day”), although it is now considered dated and obsolete.
According to the Online Etymological Dictionary,

Generally it was written as two words until 16c., after which it usually was written to-day until early 20c.


Some time thereafter, the words were joined.




References




Haycroft, Nathaniel. To-morrow and To-day; or, the Uncertainty of Life: An Element of Moral Discipline. Bristol: Chilcott, 1853.




"until early 20c" — I'm pretty sure I learned to spell "to-day" and "to-morrow" with the hyphens in the late 1950s.

Here's a "to-day" book written 110 years later: The Novel To-day. by BURGESS, Anthony.: (1963) | Shapero Rare Books

Perhaps worth noting that the 17th century KJV was often see to be using old-fashioned English even at the time, because the translators often thought this sounded more authoritative or drew from earlier 16th century translations which had become set phrases.
